# autoplay attribute plays all videos that are in django for loop

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, video.js

I'm building a web application with Django that includes a list of video generated by a for loop. Each video element has an `HTML5 video` tag with a `src` attribute pointing to a different video file, and an `autoplay` attribute set to `true`. However, when I render the page, all videos start playing at once, overlapping each other and creating a chaotic sound.

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I fix it? Is there a way to make each video start playing only when it's visible on the screen, or when the user interacts with it? Any help would be appreciated.

I want to set the videos in my for loop to `autoplay` so that when a user visits the website, there is no need to click on the `play` and `pause` icons when they want to watch different videos. What I want is for the video to stop when the user scrolls down and the next one to start playing like `facebook` videos and other social media platform, my friend suggested that, I can use JavaScript to fix that, but how can I use JavaScript to do that?

```
<div  class="container video-container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

          <div class="col-md-3 p-1">
            {% for video in my_videos reversed %}
            <div class="row position-relative my-1 wrapper">
              <video loop id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-theme-city vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-button text-center" autoplay auto="true" width="1000" controls data-setup="{}">
                <source src="{{ video.video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="row position-absolute bottom-0 d-flex align-items-end mb-3 mx-auto">
                <div class="col-md-10 col img_wrapper">
                  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{{ video.get_user_public_url }}">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-auto pe-1">
                        <img class="rounded-circle thumb" src="{{video.get_user_photo}}" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col ps-1">
                        <b class="text-white">
                            {{video.user}}
                        </b>
                        <br>
                        <small class="text-white">{{video.title}}</small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-auto video-icons d-flex flex-column">
                  <a href="">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        thumb_up
                    </span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="{% url 'Play-Video' video.slug %}">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                      comment
                    </span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="{% url 'Complain-Video' video.pk %}">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                      flag
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>

          
        </div>
      </div>
```

my css:

```
.thumb {
      width: 30px;
      height: auto;
    }
    .rounded-circle {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
    .video-icons a span{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        
    }
    video{
        object-fit: fill;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

my views:

```
def videos(request):
 
    my_videos = Video.objects.all()
    context = {
        'my_videos':my_videos,
    }
    return render(request, 'video/videos.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior I'm seeing is due to all videos starting to play simultaneously when the page loads because I have set the `autoplay` attribute to true for each video. One way to fix this issue is to add a script, so in this case:

```
<script>
    // Get all video elements
    const videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

    // Play video when it is in view
    const playVideoInView = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            const video = videos[i];
            const rect = video.getBoundingClientRect();
            const isInView = (rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight);
            if (isInView) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }
        }
    };

    // Add event listener to window for scrolling and playing videos in view
    window.addEventListener('scroll', playVideoInView);
    window.addEventListener('resize', playVideoInView);
    window.addEventListener('load', playVideoInView);
</script>
```

In this code, I select all video elements using `querySelectorAll()`. Then, I define a function `playVideoInView()` that checks if each video element is in view using `getBoundingClientRect()`. If a video element is in view, we start playing it using the `play()` method, otherwise, I pause it using the `pause()` method.

Finally, I add event listeners to the window object for the scroll, resize, and load events, which will trigger the `playVideoInView()` function whenever the user scrolls, resizes the window, or loads the page.